# Creating a extension that automatically adds a set of assemblies to every new project created

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I think the title states the problem quite well, im wondering how i can create an extension that will automatically load 2-3 assemblies to ALL projects created.

Is this hard/possible? Or is there some built-in feature in VS2010 that does this already that i seem to have overlooked?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not create a new template from File -> Export Template?

Comment: yup. Just create the project **Exactly** how you want it to look when you first start a new project. Then Export the Template.